# Shuffle/Reorder randomly the element of an RDD object with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD object made of list objects ( example: [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] ).
I need to take a sample of that and I use the sample() pyspark function for that, but it looks like it retrieves the first elements and not a random sample.

My idea was then to shuffle the elements and then use the sample() function, but I'm not able to do the randomization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`takeSample`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.takeSample):

```
rdd2 = rdd.takeSample(False, 1)
```

The first argument is whether to sample with replacement, and the second one is how many items you want to sample from the RDD.